# why we use val for LiveData in getter instead of var

Tags: android, android-livedata, mutablelivedata

I saw this code on google and I have a question about it.
in this sample they use val for viewState and use getter so if I use val I can change any thing in LiveData so using mutable live data which is created for changing items into it , but during app is not working bcs after postValue I cannot again use the getter bcs it is val....

what I mean :

1) get viewState (OK)

2)   _viewState.postvalue() (OK)

3) getviewState with changes  (NOT OK BCS ITS VAL AND DOESN;T ACCEPT CHANGES)

so is it not bad that they use val???

```
  class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private var _viewState: MutableLiveData<MainViewState> = MutableLiveData()
    val viewState: LiveData<MainViewState>
        get() = _viewState

}
```

Comment: `_viewState` should be `val`.

Comment: I asked about viewState that should be var or val

Comment: That should also be `val`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

viewState Should be val
and you no need getViewState to update the view again if already observe the viewState.

So if you need update the viewState just update _viewState

Example:

viewModel

```
 private var _viewState: MutableLiveData<MainViewState> = MutableLiveData()
    val viewState: LiveData<MainViewState>
        get() = _viewState

fun updateViewState(state:MainViewState){
   _viewState.value = state
}
```

on your Activity OnCreate or if you on Fragment OnCreateView you just need Observe the viewState

```
viewModel.viewState.observe(this,Observer{viewState->
   // Do your UI things
}
```

Comment: what is the difference between var viewState and val viewState in this code?
and if I use val viewState why It can be updated ? I mean it is val not var and shouldn't be updated

Comment: It's the exact same thing as `private final MutableLiveData<T>` vs `private MutableLiveData<T>` in Java. Just because the reference is final doesn't mean you can't change a value inside it.

Comment: so you mean get() = _viewState just change the value of LiveData which is permissible in final variables?

Comment: Wouldn't `_viewState` also be `val` opposed to `var`?